# Fetch user reviews from play store

Tags: data-science

I have just started working on Data science project and for one of the project, we need to fetch user reviews from play store. Is there any way I can fetch the reviews without using developer account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in Python, you can use google play scraper library.

You can explore this package further. Hope this helps
https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/

Comment: I am not into Python but surely will give it a try. Thanks